# Adding 'Skip' throws exception: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to fetch all rows for n groups while skipping x no of groups so I don't have to execute all records at once. In this way I can implement pagination to load data faster.

The following code is working fine (without skipping) where I am fetching all records from the first 2 groups (grouped by same Id).

```
IOrderedQueryable<Patient> query = query.OrderBy(r => r.Id);

IQueryable<Patient> groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Take(2).SelectMany(g => g);
```

But to implement pagination, when I am trying to add 'Skip' in the following way and calling `groupedQuery.ToList();`.

```
IQueryable<Patient> groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Skip(2).Take(4).SelectMany(g => g);
```

It throws the exception:

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to
>   Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method
>   'Skip'.

Can someone please suggest the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If order of groups doesn't matter to you, try adding an `OrderBy()` method before the `Skip` as below:

```
query.GroupBy(x => x.Id).OrderBy(YourOrderCriterion).Skip(2).Take(4).SelectMany(g => g);
```

The reason for the error is that as `Skip` is commonly used for paging, if you don't guarantee that your data is ordered a certain way, then the order used for retrieving the first page may differ from the order used for subsequent pages.

Comment: still strange that Skip has such a constraint, while Take has not - and they are used in pair very often.

Comment: My guess is that Take by itself isn't paging-related and so taking the top n rows without sorting is relatively harmless.

Comment: @Holger: `Skip` will _most probably_ used with paging. Why will you skip certain number of records except paging? `Take` on the other hand can be used other than paging many times -- retrieve `TOP` this number of records.

Comment: Hi @JasonTang thanks for your suggestion. While trying your suggestion, I ended up with the following working query:

```query.GroupBy(x => x.Id).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Skip(2).Take(4).SelectMany(g => g);```

Comment: @AmitJoshi The Exception is about consistence. Running the same query twice, should result in the same results. To allow some kind of randomness with take, but not with skip, is kind of inconsistent in the design. I think it's overdefined, to enforce a sorting. Most SQL-Servers do have a "natural" order and will return the records always in the same order - when you run the same query several times. Although this is most often not a feature, but it's sufficient in most cases.

Comment: It's not uncommon for Microsoft SQL Server to return the rows in different order, especially for more complicated queries.

Comment: @Holger Many EF6 behaviors (multiple cascade paths, this one) are derived from SqlServer. In this particular case, SqlServer `OFFSET … FETCH ...` can be used only after `ORDER BY`, while the (standard) SQL `TOP N` operator has no such requirements :-)